# REST API inserting into a table with 'GENERATED ALWAYS' column

Tags: sql, oracle, identity-column, oracle-rest-data-services

I'm using Oracle's Autonomous Database service, with ORDS providing the REST functionality.

When making updates to a table (docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-rest-data-services/21.2/aelig/developing-REST-applications.html#GUID-C71CF767-D4E4-475B-BEFE-0748E9EAA78E)), when I have an identity column `id` that is `GENERATED ALWAYS`, it seems the POST request even when not supplying a `id` value in the request body, gets parsed by the REST service as `id: null`.

This then gives me `Error Message: ORA-32795: cannot insert into a generated always identity column ORA-06512: at line 4`.

Using a SQL statement to insert into the table without specifying the `id` column works as expected.

Is there a way to keep the identity column always generated (so the ID of a new row cannot be specified), while allowing for POST updates?

Comment: you are using auto post, right ? it does not work with auto post, you either change the column identity generated always to a default on null, or you develop your own post method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Auto Rest functionality will always generated all columns, so there is no other solution rather than

- Develop your own `POST` method and omit on it the `IDENTITY` column
- Change the `IDENTITY TYPE`, for example from `GENERATED ALWAYS` to `GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL`, thereby Oracle will create a value when you set it to null.

I would go for the second.

```
ALTER TABLE IDENTITY_TABLE MODIFY ( ID GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY );
```

You have a great post from Jeff Smith explaining this situation

[AUTO POST and IDENTITY COLUMNS](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2020/02/the-curious-case-of-auto-rest-for-a-table-with-an-identity-column/)

Comment: Thanks - There are ways I could create something custom somewhat easily in the Oracle APEX interface also made available to the Autonomous Database service. But yes, `generated by default on null` is an easier solution for now and will just trust client apps